# Accessing context path(root folder) does not show login page in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, tomcat9, contextpath

In my **Spring Boot(2.0)** application, I have set the context path in my `application.properties` file as below

```
server.servlet.context-path=/myApp
```

Also, I have the following security configurations class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/uifiles/dist/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/uifiles/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/uifiles/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/uifiles/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/error/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/files/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/files/fonts/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/files/images/**").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .successForwardUrl("/home")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());  

    }
```

When I run the application (from **Spring Tool Suit**) and access the application via url

> **http://localhost:8080/myApp/login**

it works fine and opens the login page

But, when I enter

> **http://localhost:8080/myApp/**

it redirects me to 
**http://localhost:8080/login**  **(This gives a 404 page)**

I want both 
**http://localhost:8080/myApp/** &   **http://localhost:8080/myApp/login**
to open the login page

The login page is in located in the root of the project folder.
Also, I have `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` in my application.properties. So the controller automatically adds the file extension for the requests.

Logout functionality  works fine and it redirects to  **http://localhost:8080/myApp/login**

- **Spring Boot 2.1.7**
- **Tomcat 9.0.21**
- **JDK 1.8**

Comment: Can you add the controller code.

Comment: Are you using any reverse proxy ?

Answer (score 1):

Total stab at this - I vaguely remember this being an absolute redirect from years ago.

Try "${server.servlet.context-path}/login" as the value for loginPage.

If it works - great, if not I'll try and dig deeper into this and see what I can find.

Comment: Unfortunately owing to current COVID-19 situation I cannot check for some days. Will get back once the situation eases down.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing:
`.loginPage("/login")`
to
`.loginPage("/login.html")`

Comment: I have `login.jsp` page in the root folder and `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` in my application.properties file. So when I call `.loginPage("/login")` it will call login.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug the code add debug point in class

```
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint
```

method name `buildRedirectUrlToLoginPage`. It will be easy to trace out the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately owing to current COVID-19 situation I cannot check for some days. Will get back once the situation eases down.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `action=""` tag from `login.jsp` .